# Can't Display SQL Data on View Asp.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display SQL data on a view. But I can't on a controller:

```
var comments = (from p in ctx.Profiles
                   join sc in ctx.SuggestionComments on p.UserId equals sc.Crtr
                   join s in ctx.Suggestions on sc.SuggestionId equals s.Id
                   join u in ctx.Users on s.Crtr equals u.Id
                   where u.Email == mail
                   orderby sc.Crtm descending
                   select new { p.UserName, p.UserId, p.PhotoUrl, OneriId = s.Id, sc.Crtm }
               ).Take(10);
ViewBag.commentss = comments;
```

On view:

```
@foreach (var items in ViewBag.commentss)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @items.UserName
        </td>
        <td>
            @items.UserId
        </td>
        <td>
            @items.PhotoUrl
        </td>
        <td>
            @items.OneriId
        </td>
        <td>
            @items.Crtm
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

It's not working:

```
Additional information: 'object' a 'UserName' not contains...
```

Comment: `ViewBag.commentss` is an object. You should cast it to the correct type before enumerating through it.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag.commentss` will return an `Object`, So you can't run `foreach` loop on this.

So rather than returing anonymous type, create a class with relevant properties.
So in your case class would be like this.

```
 Public class UserDetails
    {
    public string UserName{get;set;}
    public int UserId{get;set;}
    public string PhotoUrl{get;set;}
    public int OneriId {get;set;}
    public string Crtm{get;set;}
    }
```

Now modify your `linq` query as below

```
var comments = (from p in ctx.Profiles


                        join sc in ctx.SuggestionComments on p.UserId equals sc.Crtr
                        join s in ctx.Suggestions on sc.SuggestionId equals s.Id
                        join u in ctx.Users on s.Crtr equals u.Id
                        where u.Email == mail
                        orderby sc.Crtm descending
                        select new UserDetails{UserName = p.UserName, UserId =p.UserId,PhotoUrl= p.PhotoUrl, OneriId = s.Id, Crtm =sc.Crtm }).Take(10);
        ViewBag.commentss = comments;
```

Now in view. You can typecast your viewbag as follow

```
var userDetails = ViewBag.commentss as List<UserDetails>;
```

then you can run foreach loop

```
foreach(var userDetail in userDetails )
{
  // Write your code here
}
```

Comment: var userDetails = ViewBag.commentss as List<UserDetails>;

userDetails is null on breakpoint.

And 

foreach(var userDetail in userDetails )
{
  // Write your code here
}

i can't show userDetails items on view page.

Comment: @KaanErhan : Put breakpoint at `ViewBag.commentss = comments;` and check `comments` has value of not ?

Comment: comments is not null but var userDetails is null